# E-Mail server is going down. How to make it restart as soon as it goes down?

Tags: web-services, email, smtp, plesk

I have a VPS with 256mb running a magento store. I'm running out of memory and that's causing the services to be momentarily unavailable. All but the E-Mail service come back up.

How do can I monitor the status of the service and make it restart as soon as it goes down?
How can I check what is going down exactly? pop3, smtp, or another service I don't know about?

I'm going to upgrade the VPS for 1gb of memory, but meanwhile I'd like to set this up automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use monit http://mmonit.com/monit/ or other similar daemon for inspecting your resource availability and service status

Comment: Follow up question: What does this: "Monit instance changed" mean? It's the status on my monit webpage.